# Mac OS X Cocoa: Create NCViewController with View

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsviewcontroller

I'm fairly experienced with iOS, but still pretty green with MacOS X Cocoa.

I am using InterfaceBuilder to create a view hierarchy. This is separate from the MainMenu NIB.

I am also creating an NSViewController. Because of the way that Mac OS X works, this controller object is not directly attached to the view hierarchy.

I connect all the various outlets in IB, making the view hierarchy the view object for the view controller, and attaching a few contained controls and whatnot.

Now, here's the problem: In iOS, I simply instantiate the controller from the storyboard, and the whole kit and kaboodle comes in with it. No fuss, no muss.

In Mac OS X, I can create the view controller:

```
MyAwesomeViewControllerClass *pViewController = [[MyAwesomeViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

I can't find a Mac OS X analogue to the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method in iOS. That's really what I need.

If I need to instantiate them separately, I need to figure out how to do that.

I do not want to do this programmatically. There's a lot of autolayout stuff involved, and that is a substantial (and delicate) bundle of spaghetti.

Most likely, I am going about this wrong, and would like to purchase a clue for five bucks, Alex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the name of NIB with that call to `initWithNibName:bundle:`:

```
MyAwesomeViewControllerClass *pViewController = [[MyAwesomeViewControllerClass alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"MyAwesomeViewControllerClass"
             bundle:nil];
```

I usually override `init`:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    // NOTE: Not [self initWithNibName:bundle:] !!!
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyAwesomeViewControllerClass" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Other init
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then:

```
MyAwesomeViewControllerClass *pViewController =
    [[MyAwesomeViewControllerClass alloc] init];
```

is easier to type and doesn't require users of the view controller to know the NIB being used (even if it is obvious).

Comment: Hmm.. I still must be doing it wrong. I did that, and the [self view] field is nil (same problem as before). What I need, is to have the object completely populated with its view and outlets.

Comment: That code will do it.  Your question seems to indicate that you have wired-up the NIB correctly (it implies you have made the *File's Owner* the custom view controller).  Of course accessing the `view` property is the signal for the system to actually load the NIB.  Perhaps that's it?

Comment: Oh, OK. It looks like I need to break this out into a separate nib file. I got spoiled with storyboards...

Comment: Yeah, looks like I need to break out the study books a bit more. I'm obviously not setting up the nib file correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that was interesting. I'd wired up the nib from scratch, matching an existing source file. I nuked everything, created a new view controller class from scratch (including the nib), then rewired everything. It works now. As Beetlejuice put it: "Don't you just hate it when that happens?"

Comment: @MAGSHARE That's good to hear, but it's troubling when you cannot explain *why* something doesn't work.

Comment: It has happened before, with iOS (which is why I decided to try this). Xcode can be a bit buggy; especially IB. I get a lot of crashes in IB, and I suspect there's hidden metadata that can get scragged.